Can a TON contract distinguish pending/error/success states of a tx generated by an outbound message?
Let's say I have a contract A that's supposed to start a multi-contract interaction: A calls B, C, D, and C again:
 A ---> B     C     D
 |      *     |     |
 | <--- |     |     |
 *      |     |     |
 | ---------> |     |
 |      |     *     |
 | <--------- |     |  // this may be missing if C is third-party
 *      |     |     |
 | ---------------> |
 |      |     |     *
 | <--------------- |
 *      |     |     |
 | ---------> |     |
 |      |     *     |
 | <--------- |     |  // this may be missing if C is third-party
 *      |     |     |

Now I need to only send A → D when (if and after) A → C succeeded. If C is a third-party contract, I can't expect it to send a response, can I? Is there a way to achieve this "if and after"?
I know that I can set the bounce flag to the message A → C, which will allow to distinguish "pending" vs "failed" state, but can I somehow detect "success"? send_raw_message works asynchroneously, so there's no chance to learn about "success" during the compute state. Thus, some message (or another event?) should be emitted from C and detected at A. Ideally, I'd like to use the same mechanism to detect the result on the frontend calling the initial op of A, but for frontend there's at least workaround via the APIs (like toncenter or tonconsole) that allow to get all related messages and txs.
I've checked the article by Tal Kol that explains contract sharding and followed "User story 1" (sending Jetton), but the code is not self-explanatory: (ok, let's skip the external messages stuff) what does the "revert on errors" comment mean? In my tests, if send_raw_message fails on the action phase, the code after it still computes (and that's understandable, as it's executed during the compute phase).
